# Call PHP free-function as member-function

Tags: php, closures

Consider this code example:

```
class foo { $bar = 'Hello'; }

$dump = function()
{
    var_dump($this);
};

$foo = new foo();
$bound = $dump->bindTo($foo);
$bound(); // Calls $dump which is bound to $foo instance of foo class
```

This works fine. The question is - can I do the same for free-function, but not for the Closure? Like this:

```
class foo { $bar = 'Hello'; }

function dump()
{
    var_dump($this);
}

$foo = new foo();
$bound = /* Some sort of sorcery */
$bound(); // Calls free-function dump which is bound to $foo instance of foo class
```

I've tried several ways, but still haven't made it. `dump` is not a Closure, so I can't use `dump->bindTo`. Also I can't pass function name to `Closure::bind`, either as `dump` or `'dump'` - both doesn't work. Function name without `()` is just a literal string, but not something callable. Event if I use variable function, like `$functor = 'dump'; $functor();` it is still an ordinary string and I can't convert it into `Closure`. So, is there any solution?

Comment: I don't get it. Why would you write `$this` in a normal function? Could you tell me a little bit of the background?

Comment: The same reason why do you use Closure and Closure::bindTo - to write a function what could be invoked as member-function of some object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's not natively possible. However, I found [this function](https://gist.github.com/rintaun/2773168) made by Matthew Lanigan which converts any `callable` into a closure, so you can bind it to anyhting.

Comment: Wow, that looks complicated. Looks like you are right, there is no simple solution.